# Line Break in Alert when using arrays - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, line-breaks, prompt

I´m new to Java..
I hope I can make my question easy to understand:

I trying to create a simple guess game. I use prompt() to ask for a number, if the user guesses the right number, he wins. If not, I use a while loop to prompt() the user for another guess. So far so good!

I want to do it so, that when the user guess the wrong number, the new prompt message tells the user his last guesses. For that I used an Array and the push() method. So far, so good too...

the code looks something like this:

```
var wrongGuesses = []

 /a bunch of code....

While(rightAwnser != true){

   /a bunch of code....

    var wrongGuess = lastGuess + " " +"some tips that may help";
        wrongGuesses.push(wrongGuess);
        guess = prompt(wrongGuesses);

    /a bunch of code....
}
```

My problem is that when if prompts the array (wrongGuesses), the popup box displays the arrays in a sequence and it is very hard to read. **Is there a way of displaying each array element in a different line?**

So instead of getting in the prompt box:

1257 some tips that may help, 1234 some tips that may help, 1257 some tips that may help, 1234 some tips that may help, 1257 some tips that may help, 1234 some tips that may help...

I get:
1257 some tips that may help,

1234 some tips that may help,

1257 some tips that may help,

1234 some tips that may help,

1257 some tips that may help,

1234 some tips that may help,

...
(I don´t need the blank line between each guess, just a simple enter would do. But the forum here does not allow a single enter)

I hope I could make myself clear....

And Thank You for your help!

Comment: Your title says its a java code but your post has JavaScript codein it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append  `\n` `char` in your msg at the end. That will help you to display the output in newLine.

```
wrongGuesses.push(wrongGuess+"\n");
```

Comment: Man... so easy!!!!!! I feel a little stupid now.... I actually have tried \n, but without the ""...

Thank you so much Everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use...

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

The ln brings it to the next line.

Or you can add an escape sequence after each String.

```
System.out.print(toPrint+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you iterate the array. If you want line breaks then

```
for(var i; i<wrongGuesses.length; i++){
   Window.write(wrongGuesses[i]+"\n");
}
```